# Linux system and services information

Tags: linux, ubuntu, redhat, configuration-management, devops

I am trying to create a process to fix machines in my organization. We have a few thousand  machines and what I am trying to do is the following.

A) Create a script that can create a config file (prefer in a db or plain text is ok) for each machines that include all information related to

hardware
  software - os, installed versions of packages etc
  services running - webservices, special functions

B) when the system goes down with any issue - we have sysadmins to resolve it. but then a lot gets missed. so I want to sysadmin to rerun the script to ensure that post resolution config matches the baseline configuration.

Is there a open source utility that has such capability ?

My research shows chef/puppet etc may be able to do some of this - in terms of provisioning - but we're a kickstart company and have a mature way of deployment.

I am hoping for pointers of scripts/utilities that can create baseline configs that contain system inventory & service inventories on linuxes.

ps: I realize I can comb /proc/ and get info - but I am hoping to jump into this with some open source stuff.

thanks

Comment: Consider posting in another SE forum like Ubuntu, Unix/Linux, or so. SO is not supposed to answer questions for recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

[Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) is your friend. You can add a trigger on each machine to register itself and Zabbix will start monitoring it.

More information here: [active agent auto-registration](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/discovery/auto_registration).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to do standard configuration management tools, but backwards. The standard thing to do is to use a tool like puppet or ansible (or something else of the sort) which stores the configuration for your machines, and then is able to deploy and/or compare the configured state with what happens to be present on the machine.

Comment: You are correct. unfortunately - we have already have a deployment process - and don't quite have the resources to help with puppet etc as now - so looking for a backward alternative process

Comment: This is doomed to fail in the long run, but as a band-aid you can use a tool like 'sosreport' which gathers plenty of info, including parts of the configuration and installed packages and then run a diff -u on the result.